# SceneKit move object on top of another one

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I am new to SceneKit and I am programming a game.
I have loaded two objects into my scene. The first object doesn't move, only the second one. The two objects always have to stick together but the second object can move completely free on the first object's surface depending on user input (basically like two magnets with infinity power but no friction).
My approach is to take the second object's  x and y coordinates and look what object one's z coordinate is at given x and y coordinates. Then I move object two to the exact same z-coordinate.

I tried using a SCNDistanceConstraint but it didn't have any effect:

```
let cnstrnt = SCNDistanceConstraint(target: object1)
    cnstrnt.maximumDistance = 1
    cnstrnt.minimumDistance = 0.99
    object2?.constraints?.append(cnstrnt)
```

I also tried using a SCNTransformConstraint without any effect either:

```
 let transform = SCNTransformConstraint.positionConstraint(inWorldSpace: true) { (object2, vector) -> SCNVector3 in
       let z = object1?.worldPosition.z
        return SCNVector3(object2.worldPosition.x, object2.worldPosition.y, z!)
    }
    object2?.constraints?.append(transform)
```

Using a hitTest only returns results that are positioned on the bounding box of the object and not its actual surface:

```
let hitTest = mySceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.rayTestWithSegment(from: SCNVector3((object2?.position.x)!, (object2?.position.y)!, -10), to: (object2?.position)!, options: nil)
```

So how can I get the z-coordinate of an 3d object's surface from a x and y coordinate? Because then I'd be able to set the new position of object2 manually.
Maybe you have another approach that is more elegant and faster than mine?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: One way is to add the second to the firstOne as a childNode. The other way is to add a transform constraint or distance constraints between two nodes. Direct complete calculation is always last choice.

Comment: @E.Coms thank you for your answer. I tried to make it work with this code, however  it is without effect. What am I missing? `code`let cnstrnt = SCNDistanceConstraint(target: object1)
        cnstrnt.maximumDistance = 1
        cnstrnt.minimumDistance = 0.99
        object2?.constraints?.append(cnstrnt)

Comment: Then try to figure out how the distance constraint working by another simple example

Comment: Well It doesn’t work as the distance constraint uses the position of the two nodes. However I need the distance from node1‘s surface to node2‘s surface to make my scene work properly.

Comment: How about both obj 1 and obj 2 have the same radii as 0.5